# How to create a framework from exising xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i was working on off the record app and i want to include it in my project.
i wanted to convert the off the record app to a framework in order to be able to use it.
i have been following [rayenderlish tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios) but in the final step it gives me 
"Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65"
so i was just wondering if there is another tutorial to convert the "OffTheRecord.xcodeproject" into framework

Comment: This tutorial should work, there must be something wrong with your project, make sure you have understood how every step works in that tutorial.

Comment: this tutorial for starting from beginning not on existing project?

Comment: You can begin with creating a new target which will yield a static library.